# Is it intentional that there's no mention of copyright in the FAQ?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Put in FAQ: Will submitted code be licensed under the copyleft CC-BY_SA?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/463/put-in-faq-will-submitted-code-be-licensed-under-the-copyleft-cc-by-sa)

Surely it's important for users to know whether code contributed to this site is freely available for other developers to reuse or not, and if so, under what terms. That's one of the first things I wondered about when I visited the Code Review site, so I specifically looked for it.

A search for "copyright" in meta didn't return a single result, which I find surprising!

Currently, the FAQ only has a mention of licensing in the "Other people can edit my posts?!" section, which seems inadequate given that probably every question on this site should contain substantial amounts of code.

**Perhaps the item "Did I write that code?" in the "I'm confused! What questions are on-topic for this site?" section should be updated to "*Did I write that code, and am I willing (and allowed) to share it under the Creative Commons license?*"**

[The question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/463/put-in-faq-will-submitted-code-be-licensed-under-the-copyleft-cc-by-sa) deals with the same issue, but doesn't specifically ask for an update to the FAQ.

Comment: The linked question does mention the FAQ, as such your question seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, it mentions it, but doesn't ask for it to be updated... I thought that it might be helpful to give a new-users perspective on this issue

Comment: @HiglyIrregular, that question pretty clearly asks for something to be put into the FAQ.